# How to define a generic type parameter for inner class in Java

Tags: java

I've the following interface:

```
public interface Views {
    
    interface Internal extends Public, Export {}
   
    interface Public {}

    interface Export {}
}
```

I want to write a function that'll receive a `Class` of any of the inner classes of my `Views` class. Here is a sample:

```
public String myFunction(Class viewsClass) {

}
```

How can I restrict the `viewsClass` parameter so that it'll only allow inner classes of the `Views` class? If there was a child, I would've used something like `Class <? extends Views>`. Is there anything similar for this case?

Comment: BTW there is no inner class in posted code - only nested interfaces. At least using official nomenclature - Java Language Specification [8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) states: "*An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly static.*" - an interface is not a class and always `static` ("*A nested interface is implicitly static.*")

Comment: Make an `interface MyInnerClasses { }`, have those inner classes implement (or extend for co-interfaces) it, and then you would accept a `Class<? extends MyInnerClasses>`

Comment: Another option is making the first line of myFunction `if (!Views.class.equals(viewsClass.getEnclosingClass())) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a nested class of Views: " + viewsClass);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not directly possible. Simply have all the inner classes implement the same empty interface (or the inner interfaces extend this empty interface)

Then just use the interface in the signature instead of Class<>.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to provide three overloads, one for each of your inner classes:

```
public String myFunction(Internal instance) { ... }

public String myFunction(Public instance) { ... }

public String myFunction(Export instance) { ... }
```

There is no type relationship between these inner classes; but if there is something you can do with `instance` as an `Object`, you can have these overloads each delegate to a private method:

```
public String myFunction(Internal instance) { return myFunctionInternal(instance); }

public String myFunction(Public instance) { return myFunctionInternal(instance); }

public String myFunction(Export instance) { return myFunctionInternal(instance); }

private String myFunctionInternal(Object instance) { ... }
```